# Java split() method won't work a second time

Tags: java, regex

The method updateEmployees(PersonnelManager pm)  reads a text file and depending on the first character of each line (there are 3 possiblities) on the file, it executes different code. The PersonnelManager and Employee classes have no play in the problem, that's why I'm not including them here. Here is a sample input file:

> n  Mezalira, Lucas h 40000
>
> r  5
>
> d  Kinsey
>
> n       Pryce, Lane s       50
>
> r       4

Here is the method:
(the File and Scanner objects are declared out of the method)

```
public static boolean updateEmployees(PersonnelManager pm) {
    
    try 
    {
    file = new File(updates);
    in = new Scanner(file);
    }
    
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Could not load update file.");
        return false;
    }
    
    int currentLine = 1; //Keep track of current line being read for error reporting purpose
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        
        //Check the type of update the line executes
        
        //Update: Add new Employee
        if (line.charAt(0) == 'n') {
    
            String[] words = line.split("\\s"); //Split line into words. Index [0]: update type.  [1]: last name.   [2]: first name.   [3]: employee type.  [4]: wage.
            words[1] = words[1].substring(0, words[1].length() - 1); //remove comma from last name
    
            if (words.length != 5) { //If there are not 5 words or tokens in the line, input is incorrect.
                System.out.println("Could not update. File contains incorrect input at line: " + currentLine);
                return false; 
            }
            
            if (words[3].equals("s"))  //if employee is type SalariedEmployee
                pm.addEmployee(new SalariedEmployee(words[2], words[1], Double.parseDouble(words[4])));
            
            
            else if (words[3].equals("h"))  //if employee is type HourlyEmployee
                pm.addEmployee(new HourlyEmployee(words[2], words[1], Double.parseDouble(words[4])));
            
            else {
                System.out.println("Could not update. File contains incorrect input at line: " + currentLine);
                return false;
            }
            //Display information on the console
            System.out.println("New Employee added: " + words[1] + ", " + words[2]);
        }
        
        //Update: Raise rate of pay
        if (line.charAt(0) == 'r') {
            String[] words = line.split("\\s"); //Split line into words. Index [0]: update type.  [1]: rate of wage raise
            if (Double.parseDouble(words[1]) > 100.0) { //If update value is greater than 100
                System.out.println("Error in line:" + currentLine + ". Wage raise rate invalid.");
                return false;
            }
            
            for (int i =0; i<pm.howMany(); i++) { //Call raiseWages() method for all employees handled by the pm PersonnelManager
                pm.getEmployee(i).raiseWages(Double.parseDouble(words[1]));
            }
            
            //Display information on the console
            System.out.println("New Wages:");
            pm.displayEmployees();
            
        }
        
        //Update: Dismissal of Employee
        if (line.charAt(0) == 'd') {
            String[] words = line.split("\\s"); //Split line into words. Index [0]: update type.  [1]: last name of employee
            if (words.length != 2) { //If there are not 2 words or tokens in the line, input is incorrect.
                System.out.println("Could not update. File contains incorrect input at line: " + currentLine);
                return false; 
            }
            
            String fullName = pm.getEmployee(words[1]).getName(); //Get complete name of Employee from last name
            pm.removeEmployee(words[1]);
            
            //Display information on the console
            System.out.println("Deleted Employee: " + fullName);
        }
        
        currentLine++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Since there are 5 lines in the input file, the while loop should execute 5 times, but that's not what happens. when it reaches the 4th line in the input file: "n Pryce, Lane s 50", I get an "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" error, in line 25 of the code.

The problem occurs at lines 24 and 25:

```
String[] words = line.split("\\s"); //Split line into words. Index [0]: update type.  [1]: last name.   [2]: first name.   [3]: employee type.  [4]: wage.
words[1] = words[1].substring(0, words[1].length() - 1); //remove comma from last name
```

For the 4th line of input, the "line" String is not split in 5 Strings as it should. It is only split into one, which is in words[0] and it equals "n".
What I don't understand is the program used the same line of code to split the String for the first 3 lines of input, why doesn't it work on the 4th line?

When I change the input file to

> n  Mezalira, Lucas h 40000
>
> r  5
>
> d  Kinsey

removing a second occurrence of the command "n", it works. In fact, every time I use an input file that uses the same command ("n", "r" or "d") more than once, the line where the command happens the second time will only be split into 1 string. containing the first token ( int this case "n", "r", or "d") on the line.

I hope I was clear in my explanation. If anyone know why this happens, please help.

Comment: That _cannot possibly_ be the actual code.  The `File` and `Scanner` at the top are declared inside the `try` block and go out of scope immediately, so they're not available to the rest of the code.  I do not think this code means what you think it means :-)

Comment: the File and Scanner are declared out of the method. I just added it in to post it here... I'll edit it

Comment: Do the lines really look _exactly_ like you've shown them, with _exactly one blank_ between fields? Your `split()` call should really be `split("\\s+")` to allow multiple blanks.

Comment: Not really, I was trying to post it exactly how it was on the file, but it would format automatically for me, leaving only one space between words...One line in the original file looks something like:
n Mezalira, Lucas h 40
I think that and the Scanner and File case are the only differences from the original code.

Comment: Oh! I just added the + to the split argument as you said...It worked!!
I really have no idea about Regular Expressions...Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `split()` call should really be `split("\\s+")` to allow for multiple blanks between fields.